# Div dissapears after I add script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have been trying to create an auto refreshing clock on my page but after adding script to my file the div around the clock dissapears so it doesn't use the CSS I have added to the div. `<div class="clock_item">` is the one that disapears.

If I close `div.clock_item` before `div.clocktwo` then it doesn't dissapear but I want `div.clocktwo` to stay inside `div.clock_item`.

Thanks for the help!

```js
function loadlink() {
  $('.clocktwo').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/melbourne.php', function() {
    $(this).unwrap();
  });
}

loadlink();
setInterval(function() {
  loadlink()
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock_item">


  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 310 155" style="enable-background:new 0 0 310 155;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path d="M64.9,44v102.6H36.5V44h-36V19.4h100.5V44H64.9z"/>
  <path d="M105.3,146.7V19.4h28.4v101.9h54.2v25.3H105.3z"/>
  <path d="M281.3,19.4h28.4v127.2h-28.4L220.6,67v79.7h-28.4V19.4h26.6l62.4,81.9V19.4z"/>
  <path d="M0,154.9v-9.1h309.7v9.1H0z"/>
</svg> <!--// MEL LETTERS -->

  <h3>
    MELBOURNE
  </h3>
  
  <div class="clocktwo">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, because of `$(this).unwrap();` here  [unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) remove parent element from div which is selected and in your case its `clocktwo` and its parent is `clock_item` .

Comment: Yes you're right. I replace unwrap with wrap and it is working now. You can post this as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: i am late i also did found this thing but he is first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have use `$(this).unwrap()` so unwrap removes parent element from selected element that's the reason your outer element gets removed because your selector is inner div i.e : `clocktwo` and outer is `clock_item` . Instead use `wrap` method it will wrap  html structure around each element in the set of matched elements . i.e :

```
 $('.clocktwo').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/melbourne.php',function () {
   $(this).wrap();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this can solve
don't write script in div tag

```
    <div class="clock_item">


<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 310 155" style="enable-background:new 0 0 310 155;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M64.9,44v102.6H36.5V44h-36V19.4h100.5V44H64.9z"/>
<path d="M105.3,146.7V19.4h28.4v101.9h54.2v25.3H105.3z"/>
<path d="M281.3,19.4h28.4v127.2h-28.4L220.6,67v79.7h-28.4V19.4h26.6l62.4,81.9V19.4z"/>
<path d="M0,154.9v-9.1h309.7v9.1H0z"/>
</svg>   // MEL LETTERS


      <h3>
    MELBOURNE
</h3>



    <div class="clocktwo">

</div>
  </div>
<script>
   function loadlink(){
    $('.clocktwo').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/melbourne.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); 
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() 
}, 5000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Nah mate, I have already tried that. Good guess though, thanks

Comment: ok! but you want to create clock or you want to pratice ajax code

Comment: Both at the moment

Comment: one more small guess in setinterval add semicolon loadlink();

Comment: That doesn't fix it either :/

Comment: can you give me  all code of  used in this project like melborne.php

Comment: <?php  

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');

echo date('H:i:s');

?>